# Cannot download .eml file from browser

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, eml

I've a html file which creates an eml file using JavaScript and downloads it on a button click. If I try to download without making any changes, it shows `message.eml has been blocked because this type of file can harm your system`

Now, I can download and open this .eml file if I modify  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExemptDomainFileTypePairsFromFileTypeDownloadWarnings` path in the registry and add `{"file_extension":"eml","domain":"domain.com"}` to it. But I've realized after reboot, permissions are gone, so have to set it again. I found the solution for this too. It's to make my user account the owner of the key and give full control, while keeping read-only access to System and other users for that key. It was not successful though. But anyway, I don't want to make changes in registry.

Is there a way I can download .eml files from browser without changing preset settings?

The code for downloading eml file is:

```
    <a download="message.eml" id="downloadlink" style="display: none" ><button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button></a>
        <script>
        (function () {
        var textFile = null,
          makeTextFile = function (text) {
            var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
            if (textFile !== null) {
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
            }
            textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            return textFile;
          };

          var create = document.getElementById('create'),
            textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
            if(create){
          create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');

            link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
            link.style.display = 'inline';
          }, false);
          }
          else{
            print('no create')
          }
        })();
        

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the insightful answer. But, I don't have the authority to make any permanent system changes. However, I realized later that I can still keep the .eml file in the system and open it in outlook by right clicking on the pop-up which states  ```message.eml has been blocked because this type of file can harm your system```.

Comment: Yes, you can still manually click to download the file even with the pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how you feel but I'm afraid that you can't download `.eml` files from Edge without changing the group policy or registry.

This is a feature of chromium browser which intends to protect users from harmful download files. There's a [file types policies](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/safe_browsing/content/resources/download_file_types.asciipb) in chromium and Edge inherits it. From the list, you can see that `.eml` files' danger level is `ALLOW_ON_USER_GESTURE`. That means *such files are potentially dangerous, but likely harmless if the user is familiar with download site and if the download was intentional.* For more information, you can refer to [this article](https://textslashplain.com/2021/05/19/download-blocking-by-file-type/) by Edge's Senior PM.

If you want to proceed the download of such `ALLOW_ON_USER_GESTURE` files automatically, you can set [this policy/registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#exemptdomainfiletypepairsfromfiletypedownloadwarnings). If you don't want to edit the registry, I think you can only set the corresponding group policy.